# Android Exo Player, add a View at specific position on top of Video

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, exoplayer

I am loading the video on ExoPlayer. While I play the video I want to load some UI elements on top of the video being played. To achieve this I have a layout like one below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000">
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exoplayerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/overlayContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now I am trying to place the custom UI elements on the overlay container. I have the video whose actual dimensions are  `originalWidth` and `originalHeight` , which I am trying to obtain from this call back,

```
simpleExoplayer.addVideoListener(object: VideoListener {
            override fun onSurfaceSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int) {
                super.onSurfaceSizeChanged(width, height)
                originalVideoWidth = width
                originalVideoHeight = height
            })
```

Now when the video is rendered on the device I get the current width and height using this callback,

```
override fun onVideoSizeChanged(
                eventTime: AnalyticsListener.EventTime,
                width: Int,
                height: Int,
                unappliedRotationDegrees: Int,
                pixelWidthHeightRatio: Float
            ) {
                super.onVideoSizeChanged(eventTime, width, height, unappliedRotationDegrees, pixelWidthHeightRatio)

                newVideoWidth = width
                newVideoHeight = height
                widthHeightRatio = pixelWidthHeightRatio
}
```

In the original video, the item is placed at **x** and **y**, on the device when the video is rendered it's getting new width and height, which are obtained from the above method. Now I have to find the new coordinates **x1** and **y1** based on the aspect ratio of the rendered video.

For that, I am using this code,

```
topMargin = (offsetY + (itemToBePlaced.top?.div(originalVideoHeight.toFloat()) ?: 0.0f).times(newVideoHeight)).toInt()
leftMargin = (offsetX + ((itemToBePlaced.left?.div(originalVideoWidth.toFloat()) ?: 0.0f) * newVideoWidth)).toInt()
```

In this case, I am not sure how to get the correct value for offsetY, say, for example, the View that I have to place has a coordinate position of (10,10) in the original video. Now when that is rendered on the device, I have to exactly place the item in position (10,10) with respect to the new video ratio.

When the video is rendered on the device, it is not always starting at (0,0) sometimes the video starts at (0,20) based on the aspect ratio. so if a video starts at (0,20), my element has to be placed at (0,30).

I am not sure how to successfully find the origin of the video inside the exoplayer view, in the above example, the video starts at y=20.

How can I correctly find the y position where the video starts?